# Order by menu_order and title?

Tags: pages

We can order pages by title.

Also we can sort them by menu_order.

**Is it possible, to order pages by menu_order and title at the same time?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `'orderby' => 'title menu_order'` or `&orderby=title menu_order` (depending of the syntax you use for your query parameters).

Comment: Wow. Does that work? I'll  have to try it out... It doesn't look like it should from the source...

Comment: See line 2139, wp-includes/query.php

Comment: Yup, its in there. Thanks - I never realized that was possible!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. I actually discovered it while browsing through the code. :)

Comment: wow... didn't know. looked in the codex and learned alot: none makes it empty and it really is an array exploded by spaces. already added it to the codex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't yet have enough rep to comment so I will have to post this tidbit as an answer instead.

Since WP 4.0, you may compound any of the available `orderby` values by padding them as a space-delimited list.

This is somewhat documented [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/)

> `orderby` will also parse a space-delimited set of columns:
>
> `$q = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => 'title author' ) );`
>
> Prior to 4.0, there was a problem: the value for `order` would only be
>   applied to the last value that you passed in that space-delimited list,
>   producing an `ORDER BY` clause like:
>
> `ORDER BY post_title, post_author DESC`

In answer to your question, you may use `'orderby' => 'menu_order title'`